# MVC 5 View - Set Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, c#, view, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and I have a question in regards to a `View`.

I have a `ViewModel` variable that holds a decimal value. When the `View` is displayed, I need to get this decimal value and store it in a javascript function.

Here is my `Javascript` code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var valueToStore = 29;
}
```

I know that I can make an `Ajax` call to a controller to retrieve and store this value, but can I get and store this value when the `View` loads, and the `ViewModel` has this value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: U can use a hidden field in the view which holds this viewmodel value and take that hidden fields value from javascript then.

Comment: `var myVariable = '@Model.MyDecimal';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, we create a hidden input field, where we store the value we want.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnVal" value=" @Model.YourValue"/>
```

where `YourValue` is the `decimal` you refer to.

Then we read our value like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var valueToStore = $("#hdnVal").val();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL